# router, routing, route

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [route](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/route) and [router](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/router) and [routing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/routing). I haven't inspected them closely, but I doubt there are three different meanings here.

Is there any difference in meaning between these tags?

(Note that I'm asking if the tags tend to be used with different meanings on this site, not if the words have different meanings.)

Comment: I have proposed an edit to [tag:router]. Its sitting in the approval queue currently.

Answer (score 11):

[router](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/router) seems to get questions actually about routers—the <$100 Linksys, etc. boxes. Things like loading custom firmware on them, and getting WiFi connections to work.

[routing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/routing) seems to actually get questions about IP routing. [route](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/route) seems to be the same thing. Suggest merging both to [routing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/routing).

I suggest keeping [router](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/router) for questions about the Linux aspects of the small routers that Linksys/D.Link/Netgear/etc. sell: on some you can get to the command line, on many you can install custom Linux firmwares. I suggest it not include "how do I connect my Unix box to my wireless network?". I suggest also not to include "how do I configure the stock firmware on my Linksys?" as off-topic, try Superuser.

I suggest using [routing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/routing) for questions about the IP routing features in the kernel, as well as related daemons (e.g., quagga).

Comment: `route` is standard command command, altho the description and (hence?) the questions don't reflect this...so I guess I agree that they should be merged.

Comment: @goldilocks The alternative would be to clarify [tag:route] is only for the `route` command, and then retag. Though `route` is used mainly for routing, so...